# Get a thicker \bar

Tags: math-mode, symbols

How to get a `\bar` more thicker (0.8pt for example) than usual and fit all character?

Comment: The normal syntax formatting like backticks don't work in titles and should be avoided there. Please also make sure to start the title and the text with an uppercase letter. Thanks.

Comment: Sure. I hope I'm not to annoying. :-)

Comment: Related Question (with `tikz` solution): [a bolder \overline \[duplicate\]](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164503/a-bolder-overline)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accents}
\newcommand\thickbar[1]{\accentset{\rule{.4em}{.8pt}}{#1}}
\begin{document}

$\bar A$ VS $\thickbar A$

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can change the width and height of the rule as you wish.

Comment: But when I added a `\Large` command, the thickness of `thickbar` turned thiner than in normalsize...

Comment: You can use `em` as height unit.

Comment: Am I wrong or the accents package is not available in [Miktex](http://miktex.org/pkg/browse)? Is there a substitute for Miktex?

Comment: @JuanBermejoVega: I have `accents` package in MiKTeX.

Comment: Thanks, it's solved. The problem was that `accents` is inside a bundle called `bezos`, which is the one that features in the Package Manager: [original link](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/bezos). And +1 for the help, it is nice to have this symbol  if you use overline for complex numbers.

Answer (score 10):

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\thickbar}{\mathpalette\@thickbar}
\newcommand{\@thickbar}[2]{{#1\mkern1.5mu\vbox{
  \sbox\z@{$#1\mkern-1.5mu#2\mkern-1.5mu$}%
  \sbox\tw@{$#1\overline{#2}$}%
  \dimen@=\dimexpr\ht\tw@-\ht\z@-.8\p@\relax
  \hrule\@height.8\p@ % adjust for the desired rule thickness
  \vskip\dimen@
  \box\z@}\mkern1.5mu}
}
\makeatother
```

With `\mathpalette` we make a macro that will do the right thing in all sizes. The first `\sbox` command sets the argument in the desired size (display, text, script or scriptscript); the second one sets the argument overlined; then we measure the difference, thus computing the clearance between the symbol and the bar above it. Then we draw a rule with the desired thickness, leave the computed clearance and print the symbol.

It's not exactly as wide as `\bar`, but it should be close enough.

Comment: Compare the `\thickbar` and the `\bar`, you'll find their aren't similar in length.

Comment: @Stufazi: see edit.

Comment: The `\thickbar{A}` get a undesirable accent.