# a bolder \overline

Tags: accents, bold

This is similar but hopefully not repetitive with other questions answered here... I want to use a straight line decoration above a formula to denote the mean value over observations. My main problems with `\overline` is that it is too light. I've tried the `\bm` option but it only seems to work with `\bar`, not `\overline`.  It would also be great to slightly trim the `\overline` decoration as is done with the `\overbar` command, [described in another answer on this forum](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22134/47583)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 7):

Obligatory `tikzmark` solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{%
\tikz[remember picture,baseline] \node[inner sep=0,outer sep=0] (#1){\rule{0em}{1.75em}};%
}
\newcommand\Overline[3][line width=1pt]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
      \draw[#1] (#2.north east) -- (#3.north west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\begin{document}
  \[
  \tikzmark{A}A + B = C\tikzmark{B}
  \]
  \Overline{A}{B}

  \[
  \tikzmark{A}A + B = C\tikzmark{B}
  \]
  \Overline[line width=0.5pt]{A}{B}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a lighter, macro form of the facility, that uses a node incorporating the suggestion given by egreg:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\Overline[2][1pt]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(a.base)]
      \node[inner xsep=0pt,inner ysep=1.5pt] (a) {$#2$};
      \draw[line width= #1] (a.north west) -- (a.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\begin{document}
  \[
  \Overline[1pt]{A + B = C}
  \]
  \[
  \Overline[0.5pt]{A + B} = C
  \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can this solution be made into a macro that operates similar to `\overline`?

Comment: I'm not sure `\tikzmark` is really needed; can't you just draw a line above a TikZ node?

Comment: @egreg Sure. That is also a probability. I will add it.

Comment: @cslstr There is a macro form now. :)