# How do cross out text in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, text-decorations, cancel, strikeout

Since \sout  does not work in math mode, what can I use instead?  I don't want the diagonal strikeout like with cancelf

Comment: @Mico  as I mentioned I want a HORIZONTAL slash  NOT a diagonal one   I want \sout but for math mode

Comment: One should be able to adapt the answers at [Diagonal strikeout starting too low and ending too high](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20643/4301) to get a horizontal line as it allows you to control how high you start and end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `cancel` was made exactly for this purpose.

The [manual](http://mirrors.nxthost.com/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/cancel/cancel.pdf) says that there are four different commands:

1. `\cancel`
2. `\bcancel`
3. `\xcancel`
4. `\cancelto{<value>}{<expression>}`

The first three work in math and text mode, but `\cancelto` is only for math mode.

And this is what they do

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cancel}

\begin{document}

\(\cancel{f(x)} = \bcancel{4} + \xcancel{5} - \cancelto{45}{60}\)

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is heavily based on [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16573/167081)'s comment and he deserves all the credit.

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\linethrough}{\mathpalette\@thickbar}
\newcommand{\@thickbar}[2]{{#1\mkern0mu\vbox{
    \sbox\z@{$#1#2\mkern-1.5mu$}%
    \dimen@=\dimexpr\ht\tw@-\ht\z@+2\p@\relax % The +2 represents the vertical shift of the line.
    \hrule\@height0.5\p@ % The 0.5 represent the thickness on the line.
    \vskip\dimen@
    \box\z@}}
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\mathstrike}[1]{\ensuremath{\linethrough{#1}}}

\begin{document}
    \mathstrike{f(x) = x^2},\qquad \mathstrike{c_0}, \qquad \mathstrike{f(x) = x^2 + c_0}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice answer! Just one question: how can we make the line to be *in front of* the striked out text (I made the line red, and it appears behind the text)?

Comment: @M.Winter you can redefine the `\@thickbar` as follows:`\newcommand{\@thickbar}[2]{%
 \textcolor{red}{
 {\mkern0mu\vbox{
    \sbox\z@{$#1\textcolor{black}{#2}\mkern-1.5mu$}%
    \dimen@=\dimexpr\ht\tw@-\ht\z@+2\p@\relax % The +2 represents the vertical shift of the line.
    \hrule\@height0.5\p@ % The 0.5 represent the thickness on the line.
    \vskip\dimen@
    \box\z@}}#1}
}`

and make sure to add `\usepackage{xcolor}`

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me. The line is still behind the text.

Comment: @M.Winter, it would have been easier to create a new question so I can give a complete answer than just a comment but here is another alternative:[pastebin](https://pastebin.com/JWYcqirB)